# How to be sure if a new field can be added to the pre-existing object or not?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm a `C/Python` guy, shifted to 'Javascript' recently.

Basically, I receive an object (named `context`) in a function as an argument.The caller function's definition is hidden to me. Now I need to add a field(`type`) to the `context`. When I add `type` to context directly, it doesn't reflect changes in 'context'. But when I try to modify the value of one of the existing field of 'context', this change is reflected.

Then I create one more object(`new_obj`) and copy 'context' in the 'new_object', then tried to add the field in the 'new_object', but unsuccessful. So from this behaviour, I guess the value is not copied but the reference is.

So finally I need to copy field by field in the `new_obj` and then add the new field 'type'. Also if I create a local object, then new fields are being added and object structure is modified.

So far so good. But I was wondering about the implementation of the 'context' object in background caller function. I mean if there is some 'const' type thing here(as in C, (Random thoughts :P)), then at what level it is applied i.e. there is only restriction of adding new fields or also of changing values of the existing fields. Needed some light over this issue.

Comment: It'd be much easier to see what you're talking about with some actual code, and what you expect to happen vs what is happening

Comment: A code example would really help a lot, but a couple of those paragraphs are conceptual enough to answer.

Comment: For instance, I can't imagine what you did for *"Then I create one more object(new_obj) and copy 'context' in the 'new_object', then tried to add the field in the 'new_object', but unsuccessful."* that wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder maybe he just meant `var new_obj = context`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: That would fit the symptom, yeah. Wouldn't fit "create one more object" but that could be an error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @Patrick Roberts By `var new_obj = context` I initially guessed it would create a new object, but as you're implying it didn't, which brought me here. :). Now it's clear.

Comment: @Freemn: Right, that does exactly what you said in your question: It copies the value of `context` into `new_obj` (exactly like it would if `context` contained `42`). The value is an object reference, not an object, so it's the reference, not the object, that's copied. :-)

Comment: @Freemn: (It's worth noting that that's also what happens when they pass you `context` as a function argument. Your callback, and their code, both have a reference to the same single object.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I was wondering about the implementation of the 'context' object in background caller function. I mean if there is some 'const' type thing here(as in C, (Random thoughts :P)), then at what level it is applied i.e. there is only restriction of adding new fields or also of changing values of the existing fields. Needed some light over this issue.

It depends partially on whether the object is a *host-provided object* (e.g., from the browser or similar), or a true JavaScript object.

A host-provided object can do very nearly anything it wants. :-)

A true JavaScript object can be "sealed" via [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal). That prevents new properties being added to it, but doesn't prevent changes to existing properties — exactly matching your description of `context`. Here's an example:

```js
var o = Object.seal({
  answer: 0
});
console.log(o.answer);   // 0
o.answer = 42;
console.log(o.answer);   // 42
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
console.log(o.question); // undefined
```

If you use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), trying to create a property on a sealed object is a handy error:

```js
"use strict";
var o = Object.seal({
  answer: 0
});
console.log(o.answer);   // 0
o.answer = 42;
console.log(o.answer);   // 42
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything"; // Throws error
console.log(o.question); // (we don't get here)
```

Comment: The `context` object mentioned in the question is passed when data is posted through the POST api in loopbackjs and recieved in 'before save' hook.

Comment: @Freemn: So it's probably a true JavaScript object that's been sealed. But again, code samples would really help us be sure we're not misunderstanding your descriptions. Code is worth 1024 words.

Comment: All I'm getting as argument is `context` in my function, when I POST the json payload through the REST api . And to get the code of how api's are implemented, I will have major digging to do inside the framework's existing code. In short, this is what we are left with right now. :)